# Facing issue while running aws boto3 ec2 inventory script NameError: name 'Instance_name' is not defined

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I am trying to get Ec2 inventory information from Boto3 script this script runs fine on jupyter notebook but when I am running on my project Linux environment I am getting below issue.

Name Error: name 'Instance_name' is not defined

Below is my script:

```
import boto3
import csv
import pprint as pprint
aws_mang_con=boto3.session.Session(profile_name='root')
ec2_cli=aws_mang_con.client('ec2')
cnt=1
csv_ob=open("demo3.csv","w",newline='')
csv_w=csv.writer(csv_ob)
csv_w.writerow(["S_NO","Enviroment",'Application','Componenets','Instance_id','IP','Instance_Name','Instance_Size','Status'])
response=ec2_cli.describe_instances()['Reservations']
for each_item in response:
  for instances in each_item['Instances']:
    for tags in instances['Tags']:
      if tags['Key'] in 'Name':
        name=tags['Value']
        print(name)
      elif tags['Key'] in 'Application':
        application=tags['Value']
        print(application)
      elif tags['Key'] in 'Components':
        components=tags['Value']
        print(components)  

    csv_w.writerow([cnt,'dev',application,components,instances['PrivateIpadress'],name,instances['InstanceType'],instances['State']['Name']])
    cnt+=1
csv_ob.close()
```

What else needs to be added here as it is running fine on my local jupyter notebook but on my project Linux machines it is showing above error.Any help will be much appreciated?

Comment: Please post the full traceback error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ec2.py", line 19, in <module>
    csv_w.writerow([cnt,'dev',application,components,instances['InstanceId'],instances['PrivateIpAddress'],Instance_name,instances['InstanceType'],instances['State']['Name']])
NameError: name 'Instance_name' is not defined

Comment: that traceback isn't corresponding to the code you posted.   in the code, you have ```name``` but in the traceback you have ```Instance_name```

Comment: yes I was just changing the name and testing so if we write name or instance name it  is giving the same issue

Comment: Please post the actual code you're having trouble with along with the error.   I doubt you have the same error when you changed ```Instance_name``` to ```name```

Comment: I have formated the code again @ewong

Comment: @KHYATIAMAN can you check if the formatting is correct.

Comment: @ewong its not allowing me to post code in comment the code is same and error is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ec2.py", line 19, in <module>
    csv_w.writerow([cnt,each_item['OwnerId'],application,components,instances['InstanceId'],instances['PrivateIpAddress'],Instance_name,instances['InstanceType'],instances['State']['Name']])

Comment: @ArunK where i need to format?

Comment: I have formatted the code in the question.  is your `csv.write` line is aligned with `for tags in instances['Tags']:` ?

Comment: @KHYATIAMAN ```Instance_name``` isn't defined in your code.  thus your error.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ArunK its working fine now.Issue got resolved

Comment: what was the issue, indentation ?

Comment: yes @ArunK indentation was issue

Answer (score 0):

I think the following line is incorrectly indented.

```
csv_w.writerow([cnt,'dev',application,components,instances['PrivateIpadress'],name,instances['InstanceType'],instances['State']['Name']])
```

the indententation should be same as the line that says `for tags in instances['Tags']:`

it should be like this:

```
for instances in each_item['Instances']:
  for tags in instances['Tags']:
    # assign the value to variables
    #
  csv_w.writerow([cnt,'dev',application,components,instances['PrivateIpadress'],name,instances['InstanceType'],instances['State']['Name']])
    cnt+=1
csv_ob.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it has 9 parameters in both header and csv